# Powering Motor with Raspberry pi and h-bridge

Tags: pi-3, power-supply, dc-motor, bridge

I am trying to control a 3-6 volt motor with a raspberry pi and h-bridge. I have a separate power source for my pi and my motors.

I have tried a 6v, 9v, and 12v power source. However, the motor buzzes but will not turn. (The motors turn when power is directly applied).

I am using the code supplied in this link: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/physical-computing/16

Is it possible the H-bridge is fried, or is the voltage drop that great? Any suggestion would be great. Also if there is a better way to directly control the motors I am all ears.

[image: Pi and Motor setup]

Comment: I can't make out the connections between the Pi and the motor driver board.  Could you edit your question and clarify which wires are connected from the Pi to which points on the motor driver board? If I had to guess I'd say you have not connected a Pi ground to the motor driver board ground.

Comment: please post the actual code that you used .... do not post a link to a website that has a bunch of code .......... add the code to your question ...... **do not** put it into a comment

Comment: @joan it looks to me like there's a black/white zipcord going from controller to GPIO, but we can't see which ping.  So, the question for Cam is what pins are those wares connected to.

Comment: @BobBrown Yes, it looks like GPIO 2/3 (pins 3/5) are connected to IN3/IN4.  I'm fairly sure the underlying problem is the missing ground connection.

Comment: @joan  That would explain it.  (You've got better eyes than I do, too!)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ground / common connection between Pi and the driver board

Answer (score 1):

You must connect GND pin of your raspi to ground of bridge (- of battery) 
Then you can use these code for test :

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM) #setpinout as BCM

#Motor1
gpio.setup(m1in1, gpio.OUT) #m1in1 = motor 1 input 1
gpio.setup(m1in2, gpio.OUT) #m2in2 = motor 1 input 2
gpio.output(m1in1,True) #Set first pin High
gpio.output(m1in2,False) # Set second pin LOW 
# This High Low Setting means dc motor will turn forward ( Low - High means backward)

# set enable pin as output pin
gpio.setup(m1en,gpio.OUT)
m1=gpio.PWM(m1en,1000) # 1000 Hz frequency
m1.start(0)
```

Then you can use the command :

```
m1.ChangeDutyCycle(x) #where 0<x<100
```

That way you can learn how slow and faster your motor can turn. Some motors start turning when x = 25 , some are x = 50..

Here you can find a tutorial about PWM [Raspberry Pi PWM Tutorial](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi-pwm-tutorial)

*You must use enable pin for this tutorial